# Почему предпочтительнее написать "сегодня такой теплый денек"?

Tags: стилистика

Почему предпочтительнее написать "сегодня такой теплый денек!" чем "сегодня такой хороший теплый денек", в чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из Вашей логики, следует допустить, что зимой хороших деньков быть не может. Думаю, никакой стилистической погрешности во  втором предложении нет. Я бы поставила запятую: "Сегодня такой хороший, теплый денек".

Answer (score 0):

Потому что во втором случае получается явный перегруз с определениями, что утяжеляет предложение.

Answer (score 0):

Выберите вариант "сегодня такой хороший денёк" либо "сегодня такой тёплый денёк".

Answer (score 0):

Первое написание не является предпочтительным. Это заблуждение. Когда автор высказывания хочет подчеркнуть то, что день является хорошим, он вполне может это сделать введя дополнительный эпитет.

Answer (score 0):

Стилистическая тавтология.
*Хороший* не добавляет ничего к общей хактеристике "денька". Хороший день - это и есть теплый и солнечный.  Комому-то, в том числе и говорящему или слушающему, конечно, может показаться, что это не так - и в теплом деньке нет ничего хорошего, но все-таки надо считаться со сложившимися эпитетеами.
Хотя надо сказать, ошибка это не из тех, что "бьёт по ушам". Так, некоторая стилистическая шероховатость.

Answer (score 0):

"Мороз и солнце - день чудесный". Хороший денек может быть с трескучим морозцем, наступившем после слякотного зимнего тепла. Не вижу никакого равенства между "хорошим" и "теплым". Для меня хороший - скорее солнечный и безветренный.